# Why does my ajax login script won't work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need an AJAX Login Script for my school project.
But it actually won't work because when I try to login, I get kicked to the startpage (login-form) without any message.

That's my backend-script (login2.php):

```
if(empty($_POST['loginEmail']) || empty($_POST['loginPassword'])) {
    $error[] = "Bitte füllen Sie alle Felder aus!";
}
if (!empty($_POST['loginEmail']) && !filter_var($_POST['loginEmail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error[] = "Bitte geben Sie eine gültige E-Mail-Adresse an!";
} 
if(count($error)>0) {
    $resp['msg'] = $error;
    $resp['status'] = false;
    echo json_encode($resp);
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uEmail` = :email AND `uPassword` = :password";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['loginEmail']));
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(count($row)>0) {
    if(!password_verify($_POST['loginPassword'],$row[0]['uPassword'])) {
        $error[] = "Falsches Passwort!";
        $resp['msg'] = $error;
        $resp['status'] = false;
        echo json_encode($resp);
        exit;
    }
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['Email'] = $row[0]['uEmail'];
    $resp['redirect'] = "dashboard.php";
    $resp['status'] = true;
    echo json_encode($resp);
    exit;
}
else {
    $error[] = "Falsche E-Mail-Adresse!";
    $resp['msg'] = $error;
    $resp['status'] = false;
    echo json_encode($resp);
    exit;
}
```

And this is my JS part of the login form:

```
$(function() {
    $('#login').click(function(e){
        let self = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        self.prop('disabled',true);
        var data = $('#login-form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/login2.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
        }).done(function(res) {
            res = JSON.parse(res);
            if(res['status']) {
                location.href = "dashboard.php";
            } else {
                var errorMessage = "";
                console.log(res.msg);
                $.each(res['msg'],function(index,message) {
                    errorMessage += '<p>' + message + '</p>';
                });
                $("#error-msg").html(errorMessage);
                $("#error-msg").show();
                self.prop('disabled',false);
            }
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        }).always(function(){
            self.prop('disabled',false);
        });
    });
});
```

When I try to add `action="/login2.php"` in the form I get a HTTP 500 Error and the message, that it can not process this request at this time.

Comment: enable errors in PHP: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php-troubleshooting/troubleshoot-php-errors and see what is causing that 500 error

Comment: Ah. The memories of school programming where login.php didn't work and you created login2.php to not overwrite previous work. Are you not able to get any more detailed errors?

Comment: "When I try to add action="/login2.php" in the form" ...why would you need to do that? If ajax is working properly then the URL to which the data is submitted is determined by the line `url: '/login2.php'` in the ajax settings. So changing the action should make no difference. That is of course assuming you have bound the JS event to the submit button correctly, and it isn't doing a standard postback instead...but since we can't see the form code, we can't be sure about that. What debugging have you done? Does your JS code and ajax call definitely get executed?

Comment: P.S. I notice that, after a successful login, you are sending the user to another page (via the line `location.href = "dashboard.php";`). Since you are doing that, what is actually the purpose of making your login via AJAX? The whole reason AJAX exists is to allow you to talk to the server but also _stay on the same page_. If you're just going to immediately re-direct the moment the ajax succeeds, then it's really a bit pointless to use AJAX at all. You might as well do a standard postback, and define the redirect server-side instead - and then save yourself a lot of JS code in the process.

Comment: @ADyson i've seen a lot of questions about ajax with the same behaviour. Never been able to make OP understand how little sense this does

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your main problem, but it's a significant one. You're preparing two parameters:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uEmail` = :email AND `uPassword` = :password";
```

But you're only binding one:

```
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['loginEmail']));
```

You don't want to include the password in the select, since you're using `password_verify()` to validate it later. Change your SQL to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uEmail` = :email";
```